# SQL 2008 SP1 on XP

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is SP1 for Microsoft SQL 2008  supported on Windows XP?
The list of supported OSes doesn't have XP. But SQL 2008 STD Edition is supported on XP SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008 on Windows XP SP3 and Windows Server 2003 SP2.

I have installed it on both Windows XP SP3 32Bit and Windows XP SP2 64Bit without issues. I have also successfully deployed it on Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Comment: I am talking about Service Pack 1 for SQL 2008. The supported OS tab does not include Vista & XP.

Comment: I am also referring to Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008. These are a list of platforms I have successfully deployed the Service Pack. Will update the Answer accordingly.